# Hotel communication microservice

Tags: microservices

In a microservice architecture for a hotel I want to create a communication service that will handle all the emails, sms, ... This service should be triggered by asynchronous events.

Should these events be called: SEND_RESERVATION_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL, making the reservation service aware of the email communication. Or should there be a more generic event RESERVATION_CONFIRMED, resulting in a confirmation email?

Answer (score 2):

> Should these events be called: SEND_RESERVATION_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL

No. Events should be named as sentences in the past.

> making the reservation service aware of the email communication

I would not make that coupling. The reservation service is responsible with reservations, not with methods of notifying the customers.

> Or should there be a more generic event RESERVATION_CONFIRMED, resulting in a confirmation email?

Yes, `RESERVATION_CONFIRMED` seems a good choice; it represent **what really had happened** and it does not contain indication of what should be done next. The workflow/process of notifying the customer should be managed by another component, i.e. a Saga/Process manager. This Saga would receive the `RESERVATION_CONFIRMED` event and then would send `SEND_RESERVATION_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL` **command** to the responsible microservice.